# Show that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n(\sqrt{n}+\sin n)} $ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to prove that the following series converges:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n(\sqrt{n}+\sin n)}
$$
I tried to use Dirichlet's test but I was not really sure whether the denominator is a monotonically decreasing function. If it is than the problem becomes easy.

Comment: Note that this series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \leq |\frac {\sin n}{n(\sqrt n+\sin n)}| \leq \frac 1 {n(\sqrt n -1)}$ for all $n >1$. Compare $\sum \frac 1 {n(\sqrt n -1)}$ with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{3/2}}$ to show that it is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n >4$.

$0\le |\dfrac{\sin x}{n(√n+\sin x)}|\lt \dfrac{1}{n(√n-1)} $

$\lt \dfrac{1}{n(√n-(1/2)√n)}=2\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$;

Comparison test.